# Denotion of Cronbach's Alpha based on Polychorric Correlations

Tags: descriptive-statistics, reliability, psychometrics, cronbachs-alpha

we assessed several 5 point Likert-Scale items in a questionnaire and are interested
in Cronbach's $\alpha$ for the internal consistency.
I recently read ([here](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-94-007-0753-5_2025)) that it can be more precise to used instead $\alpha$  based on polychoric correlations for such type of data.
Since I want to report the alpha in an abstract (with very limited space) I was wondering if there is common denotion for $\alpha$  based on polychoric correlations, e.g. $\alpha_c$ or something along this line?